# Win32 API Call to specific X Y Coordinate of Window Handle

Tags: c#, winapi, coordinates

Well, the project has moved along rather nicely and we have a pretty darn good product, but a wrench has been thrown into the gear works.

We have a C# 2012 application that interacts with another application (written in VB 6 of all things) and we can do a good bit with it so far, but we have a problem.

We need to select a button on a toolbar at the top of this particular application's window, but the button is not available through an API search. We have the main window's handle and can see all of its children, but I think the Toolbar is a User type control that we can't access through the API Calls. This application is very poorly designed and we had to do a LOT of work just to discover TWO User ID text boxes on the logon screen.

Anyway, my question is this: How would I set up a call to the main window and click a certain X, Y coordinate of that window's viewable area? I am using SendMessage to send mouse clicks to press a button control already, but if I can't get access to that button control, the idea was to send mouse clicks to a specific coordinate of the window.

Any ideas folks? Thanks!

Comment: Use Spy++ (part of the Windows SDK) to find out what window receives the messages in normal use (interactive with a real mouse).  Or even better, find out what `WM_COMMAND` or `WM_NOTIFY` id the toolbar button sends to its owner, and just send that, bypassing the mouse-clicky type messages.

Comment: Would I use those parameters (WM_COMMAND, WM_NOTIFY) in the Send Message method to return that information? My Win32 API knowledge is about 6 months old. :-D

Comment: No, you'd use Spy++ to discover the message arguments sent from the toolbar button to the main window, and then you could use `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, stuff learned from Spy++)` to tell the app its toolbar was clicked.

Comment: This, of course, implies, that the button actually does send a message to the window. With this button being some homebrew thingy, it might just do what it must do in its `WM_LBUTTONCLICK` handler. If that is the case, you'd have to go about using [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) to synthesize mouse input. Note that you cannot send input to a particular window. Input is global.

Comment: If you really want to literally click the screen then use the GetWindowRect() API to get the (x, y) location of the main window, then simply add an offset to that to click the button using the mouse_event() API.  This assumes that the position of the button doesn't changed with respect to its own UI.

Comment: Not a bad idea there @Idle_Mind. I've been floundering about trying to figure out the configuration for Spy++ to track the right messages. So far, no luck there. I just don't have enough experience to set the search properties right. IInspectable ... that is very much a possibility. It's a very old application (VB 6) and the controls are custom made. Their Class names look like this: ThunderRT6Textbox. Everything is ThunderRT6 something. So, yeah. Not native Windows controls.

Comment: Actually, all the stock VB6 class names began with "ThunderRT6"...that's the way they came.

Comment: Bit of [history](http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1166/530689453_945c53e072_o.jpg) for you...

Comment: Excellent. That explains quite a bit ... Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us which strategy you intent to implement, and if you have probem with it

Comment: I will. I am still working on some of the pieces to fit together as Spy++ cannot see the buttons on the Toolbar as separate pieces. I am thinking that the solution is going to be the Get Window Rectangle suggestion.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions. I appreciate all of your time and effort in answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the solution will be to get the Window's rectangle and add the offset in order to use the mouse event API call.

Thank you to @Idle_Mind for the suggestion. It is at least working on our test environment. It will be next week before we can test the solution out in our client's environment.